# Python Join not working as expected

Tags: python-2.7

**Python 2 Code:**

```
healthamzn = "E:\ACADEMICS\PEC---\ME 4 SEM\code\data\amazon5core\healthcare"
jester = "E:\ACADEMICS\PEC---\ME 4 SEM\code\data\jester"

print(os.path.join(healthamzn, "healthcare5core.csv"))
print(os.path.join(jester,"jester_ratings.dat"))
```

**Output:**

`E:\ACADEMICS\PEC---\ME 4 SEM\code\datamazon5core\healthcare\healthcare5core.csv
E:\ACADEMICS\PEC---\ME 4 SEM\code\data\jester\jester_ratings.dat`

Please see that first output is not what I expected.

**Expected Output:**

`E:\ACADEMICS\PEC---\ME 4 SEM\code\data\amazon5core\healthcare\healthcare5core.csv`

Comment: How come `E:\ACADEMICS\PEC---\ME 4 SEM\code\datamazon5core\healthcare\healthcare5core.csv` is different from `E:\ACADEMICS\PEC---\ME 4 SEM\code\datamazon5core\healthcare\healthcare5core.csv`? If you want to omit the line `E:\ACADEMICS\PEC---\ME 4 SEM\code\data\jester\jester_ratings.dat` just remove the last line of your code.

Comment: Backslashes have special meaning in Python string literals - specifically, `\a` is an escape sequence for the BEL character.  You either need to double the backslashes to escape them, use a raw string literal (`r"..."`) to avoid this interpretation of backslashes, or possibly use forward slashes (they work just as well everywhere in Windows except the command line).